# How do I get my BTC back into my exchange without losing my BCC?

Tags: wallet

I put my BTC in a paper wallet before the fork. Now, I'm desperately looking for a way to get my BTC off my paper wallet and back into circulation without losing my BCC. I don't really want to send my BTC to a newly developed BCC-dedicated wallet (because it's a large amount and that makes me nervous), but to my understanding sending my coins back to Gemini will make my lose my BCC.

Answer (score 1):

Just send your BTC where you want to send to. As replay protection is implemented, your BCC will stay at your paper wallet, and you'll be able to spend your BCC.